# Dapperextension mapping functionality

Tags: dapper-extensions

Is there a way with the dapperexstension mapping to map an object to a value (id) when the object is a property of another object. Here is an example.

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

The table in the database for Contact will have this 3 columns

- Id
- Name
- AddressId

So when I save the Contact with the **connection.Insert<>** function I want the **Address** be converted to **Address.Id** and mapped to the AddressId column in the Contact table.

I know that I can add a AddressId property in my Contact class and then it will be saved. But then I pollute my Contact class only to make it used by Dapper. There is also the way to not use the **connection.Insert** method but instead write a Sql Insert statement and use that in a **connection.Query**. But then I must remember to change the SQL Statement as soon as I change the Contact class.

So I am looking for something like this.

```
Map(m => m.Address).Columns("AddressId").UseValue(m.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

DapperExtensions is a simple orm overlay. We do not currently have any plans to support aggregate objects.